# I can't get the nav drawer on screen : android

Tags: android

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="com.example.cortana.testing.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
                app:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
                android:titleTextColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                >

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/textTabUnselected"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/textTabSelected">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.example.cortana.testing.activity.FragmentDrawer">

    </fragment>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here is the fragment_navigation_drawer.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_header_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_profile"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/nav_header_container"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, I need to have a system where both navigation drawer and a tablayout are present on the same activity. According to the `activity_main.xml`, they should be too. But the output currently is:
[image_current_android_app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewkCm.jpg)

What am I missing here and how do I allow a nav-drawer icon (the hamburger icon) to come up on the screen.

EDIT:

I have worked the solution into my code. Now the output looks like this: [image: new_output_android].
In the menu, I need to make the overflow icon's color white. 
I've tried this:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->

    <!--    
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    -->

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base"></style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>    
</resources>
```

This didn't help and other solutions that are available are really tedious (involving adding a few java and xml's). Is there a way to do this simply?

EDIT2: found the solution

just add this line to the styles.xml and it will work

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/WHITE</item>
```

Comment: The hamburger icon comes from using a v7 `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. Are you creating one of those in your Java code?

Comment: Wow thanks. Guess I missed that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare this in your `Activity`.

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
```

inside `onCreate` method

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);

 toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,toolbar ,  R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) { 

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */ 
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            //invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        } 

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */ 
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            //getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            //invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        } 
    }; 


    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener 
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

and Make sure that you have following `import`

```
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

if you write this code in `Activity` the `hamburger icon` is display in the screen.

Comment: @daenerys glad to help you.